# CSV upload not working in python

Tags: python, file-upload, csv

I'm writing an app in python to upload a csv file and process it.  I'm using a form to upload it so I've got:

**form.html**

```
<form method="post" enctype = "multipart/form-data" >
{% csrf_token %}
           <p><input type="file", name="docfile"></p>
           <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
</form>
```

**models.py**

```
def process(request, name):
Entries = []
table = {}
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CSVFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        foo = csv.reader(request.FILES['docfile'])
        for rows in foo:
            pass
```

**forms.py**

```
class CSVFileForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField()
```

Just to show the problem.  The problem is that at the iteration, I get the error "iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)".  The sample code in csv opens the csv file as 'rb' and when I try to process the file that I'm trying to upload, the sample code works as expected.  However, here it looks like the data type is not correct.  I've tried making the upload text, but that creates other problems.

Thanks

Comment: this looks like flask, have you tried just using the flask-uploads extension?

Comment: No, this is straight python, and I thought should be doable within python.